# TI Basic multitasking (TI-84+)

Tags: basic, ti-basic

Within the TI basic in calculator programming, (not the the external programming), is it possible to create a multitask? Like the calculator would be able to run two threads or codes at a time?

I just found results of multithreading within the external programming of a TI calculator. Otherwise I couldn't find any about the ti calculator. So im asking if it is possible to multitask.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What attempts have you made to solve your issue? It is expected from Askers to show research effort.

Comment: I have researched about it and I couldn't find any results of that. That's why im asking it here.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification. It's correct and good that you also pointed that out in the question itself.

Comment: Could you also clarify what you mean by external programming, and why you need to use multiple threads so we can help you with that?

Comment: The regular TI OS does allow CPU interrupts, but those are only accessible by programming in Assembly or AXE. The only way to do such in TI-Basic would be to create a sub program in Asm/Axe and run that from inside the Basic program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot run multiple threads of code at the same time with TI-basic. With an OS or shell, like KnightOS or MirageOS, you can run multiple programs at the same time I believe, but that's probably not what you need.

Comment: KnightOS does allow multitasking (though it's a *very* unfinished OS, and not really usable). MirageOS is a prgram shell/launcher, not an OS and does not allow multitasking.